# Thread locking in WPF, with Dispatcher Timer

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a WPF C# application, that uses Dispatcher Timers to update the UI.

In Thread A, in a Class `DataProcessor`, I am updating a variable, a custom struct called 'FinalMarkers'.

I am locking the variable update using the following:

```
 static readonly Object mLock = new Object();
            static List<Storage.FiducialMarkers> finalMarkers;
            public List<Storage.FiducialMarkers> FinalMarkers
                {
                    get { return finalMarkers; }
                    set
                    {
                        lock (mLock)
                        {
                            finalMarkers = value;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

and then inside the thread run:

`FinalMarkers = pullFiducialData();`

In my UI Form, I am passing the instance of `DataProcessor` to the Form's constructor.

```
        protected DataProcessor Data = null;

 public FormView(DataProcessor _Data)
        {
                       Data = _Data;
          }
```

I then have a dispatcher timer that calls the variable:

```
 DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20);
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick3d;
            timer.Start();
```

in the timer tick function, i grab the values:

```
        List<Storage.FiducialMarkers> tmpList = new List<Storage.FiducialMarkers>();

 tmpList = Data._processingArgs.FinalMarkers;
```

This will run for a while, then crash without error. Am I handling the thread locking wrong?

Is this the correct way to pass data from another thread into a dispatcher timer?

Thank you.

Comment: I doubt it's related to your lock. As implemented it just does nothing useful. You have to figure out what exception is thrown and include its stack trace and message.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the lock in `get` as well as `set`.

```
public List<Storage.FiducialMarkers> FinalMarkers
    {
        get {
            lock (mLock) {
                return finalMarkers;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (mLock)
            {
                finalMarkers = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

If you take the lock when you are calling `set`, then you protect yourself from two setters running at the same time, but if you don't take the lock when you are calling `get` then the set may tamper with the value while it is being read by an uncoordinated reader; and this will happen regardless of whether the writer is holding a lock or not.  The lock is an agreement between multiple threads.  If only one thread (the writer) is bound to the agreement, then the other thread (the reader) is going to wind up performing its read at an inopportune moment and potentially cause some kind of conflict or corruption.

The lock says "let's not do this block of code at the same time".  You have to get all threads to agree by putting any code involved in accessing `finalMarkers` inside lock blocks.

FYI: The struct itself has value semantics so it is copied when doing the get.

Comment: Thank you! This runs for longer, but then i am getting: `Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at FormView.timer_Tick3d(Object sender, EventArgs e) ` Is this likely also a thread safety issue, or could I have missed something else?

Comment: @anti You have exactly the same problems with this change as you do without it.  You're still accessing the same list from multiple threads at the same time, and you can't do that.

Comment: Thank you. What is the accepted way to tackle a problem like this? Will a read/write lock not do it?

Comment: @anti You need to ensure that you never access the list from multiple threads at the same time.  You also need to ensure that you aren't blocking the UI thread, so synchronization mechanisms that involve waiting, like `lock` need to be used carefully (or not at all) to ensure that the UI stays responsive.

Comment: Ah I see. So most likely it is the UI factor that is getting me here?  Is there a way around this? In c++ I would use `boost::shared_mutex Lock;` for this kind of thing, but i am lost in WPF